# Why I have multiple PFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data and how to deal with it

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning, disk-utility

I own MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) with macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 (19H15).

The device underwent two liquid split repair services, after each I setup it from what looked to me as factory settings state. Some time ago, I attempted to "Erase and reinstall macOS", following some guide found online (I cannot locate it as of today).

I have recently realized I am running out of storage on my Mac fast. The `About this Mac > Storage` indicates that major chunk of the storage is labelled `Other Volumes in Container`:

[image]

I also learned the `diskutil list` returns:

```
martakaras@Martas-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     391.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     45.0 GB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 82.3 MB    disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.1 GB    disk1s6

martakaras@Martas-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

I am now wondering if the `APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     391.3 GB   disk1s1` is basically some partition (volume) I no longer use, and that unnecessarily keeps taking space. I presume it might be a result of (a) liquid split damage service action, or (b) mine "Erase and reinstall macOS" action.

How can I "look up" what is at `APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     391.3 GB   disk1s1` to decide if I can safely remove it (free-up space)? By safely I mean assuring that no essential for the system files are there (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential system files are all in "Macintosh HD". User files are in Macintosh HD - Data".

As you appear to have two of those, you can delete either.
One of them, presumably the larger one, is likely to contain files you had before the repair. You can use Disk Utility to mount & inspect its contents.
If there's nothing on there you need, then you can remove the partition.

macOS's container structure will then allow the other volume to dynamically use [almost] the entire container for your solo Macintosh HD - Data volume. Volumes within a container don't really have a size, their boundaries are flexible.